# Failed to initialize Atmosphere Framework on vaadin 14

Tags: wildfly, vaadin-flow, java-ee-8, vaadin14

I have added Vaadin 14 flow in the existing JavaEE 8 application which has Perimeface 6.2 implementations on the frontend using Wildfly 18 as a server container.
The application runs okay but before deployment, I get the following error.
I have searched on the web but couldn't figure out why it happens.

I know it has to do with Java API for WebSocket and Vaadin servlet has tried the following.

Added dependency to the pom.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
    <artifactId>flow-push</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Added `@push` to the main Vaadin class. 
`import com.vaadin.flow.component.page.Push;`

**Does anyone know what is the reason and how can be solved?**

Vaadin servlet config:

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>Vaadin Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>i18n.provider</param-name>
            <param-value>translation.TranslationProvider</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
```

**error is as below:**

```
ERROR [org.atmosphere.util.IOUtils] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 6) : java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:862)
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.next(Collections.java:1042)
    at org.atmosphere.util.IOUtils.guestRawServletPath(IOUtils.java:290)
    at org.atmosphere.util.IOUtils.guestServletPath(IOUtils.java:255)
    at org.primefaces.push.impl.PushEndpointMapper.configure(PushEndpointMapper.java:47)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework.initEndpointMapper(AtmosphereFramework.java:1791)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework.init(AtmosphereFramework.java:911)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework.init(AtmosphereFramework.java:838)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.PushRequestHandler.initAtmosphere(PushRequestHandler.java:218)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.JSR356WebsocketInitializer.initAtmosphereForVaadinServlet(JSR356WebsocketInitializer.java:184)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.JSR356WebsocketInitializer.init(JSR356WebsocketInitializer.java:149)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.JSR356WebsocketInitializer.contextInitialized(JSR356WebsocketInitializer.java:118)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.startup.ServletContextListeners.contextInitialized(ServletContextListeners.java:42)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:187)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:217)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:186)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1541)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1541)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1541)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1541)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1541)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:252)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:96)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:78)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:485)

11:38:55,617 ERROR [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 6) Failed to initialize Atmosphere Framework: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to configure jsr356 at that stage
    at org.atmosphere.util.IOUtils.guestRawServletPath(IOUtils.java:297)
    at org.atmosphere.util.IOUtils.guestServletPath(IOUtils.java:255)
    at org.primefaces.push.impl.PushEndpointMapper.configure(PushEndpointMapper.java:47)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework.initEndpointMapper(AtmosphereFramework.java:1791)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework.init(AtmosphereFramework.java:911)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework.init(AtmosphereFramework.java:838)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.PushRequestHandler.initAtmosphere(PushRequestHandler.java:218)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.JSR356WebsocketInitializer.initAtmosphereForVaadinServlet(JSR356WebsocketInitializer.java:184)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.JSR356WebsocketInitializer.init(JSR356WebsocketInitializer.java:149)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.JSR356WebsocketInitializer.contextInitialized(JSR356WebsocketInitializer.java:118)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.startup.ServletContextListeners.contextInitialized(ServletContextListeners.java:42)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:187)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:217)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:186)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1541)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1541)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1541)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1541)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1541)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:252)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:96)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:78)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:485)

11:38:55,618 WARN  [com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.JSR356WebsocketInitializer] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 6) Failed to initialize Atmosphere for Vaadin Servlet: java.lang.RuntimeException: Atmosphere init failed
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.PushRequestHandler.initAtmosphere(PushRequestHandler.java:227)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.JSR356WebsocketInitializer.initAtmosphereForVaadinServlet(JSR356WebsocketInitializer.java:184)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.JSR356WebsocketInitializer.init(JSR356WebsocketInitializer.java:149)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.JSR356WebsocketInitializer.contextInitialized(JSR356WebsocketInitializer.java:118)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.startup.ServletContextListeners.contextInitialized(ServletContextListeners.java:42)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:187)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:217)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:186)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1541)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1541)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1541)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1541)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1541)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:252)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:96)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:78)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:485)
Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to configure jsr356 at that stage
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework.init(AtmosphereFramework.java:955)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework.init(AtmosphereFramework.java:838)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.PushRequestHandler.initAtmosphere(PushRequestHandler.java:218)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to configure jsr356 at that stage
    at org.atmosphere.util.IOUtils.guestRawServletPath(IOUtils.java:297)
    at org.atmosphere.util.IOUtils.guestServletPath(IOUtils.java:255)
    at org.primefaces.push.impl.PushEndpointMapper.configure(PushEndpointMapper.java:47)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework.initEndpointMapper(AtmosphereFramework.java:1791)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework.init(AtmosphereFramework.java:911)
    ... 28 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following to the servlet fixed the issue. Hopefully can save someone time and energies :)

```
        <init-param>
            <param-name>pushmode</param-name>
            <param-value>automatic</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>org.atmosphere.websocket.suppressJSR356</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
```